# Connecting to play games appear but nothing happens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have added a google sign in button and I have correctly implemented all the sign in keys and certificates
So when I tap on my sign in button
"Connecting to play games" appear then the green circle appears for 1 second and boom nothing happens after that I am calling signIn from a button and authentication is done at start. Please help

Note: I am making this game in unity and I am using play games plugin latest version (0.10.11)

```
public class PlayGamesController : MonoBehaviour {

private void Start()
{
    AuthenticateUser();
}

public void AuthenticateUser()
{
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}
public void SignIn()
{
   
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Logged in to Google Play Games Services");

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Unable to log in to Google Play Games Services");
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Also, I have made 2 linked credentials for both the sign in keys and the keys matches my keystore and play console keys so no problem even there, I searched literally everywhere and can't seem to work it out, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was, I had one more google account added in my phone along with the test account and I just had to remove the other one and boom, it logged in successfully. So for anyone who's having this or might have it ever, watch out on the accounts you have other than the test account.